# Convert a string (Last\tFirst\tAge) to an array with elements {Last, First, Age}

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm new to Java and I want to convert a string such as `Apple\tJohn\t23`(note `\t` are tabs) into an array with 3 elements `{Apple, John, 23}`. I know that I need to some import some string manipulation method but I'm only beginning Java so is there one that fits my situation?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want:

```
String[] bits = text.split("\t");
```

Note that [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression - so if you ever want to split on a dot, you'd need `split("\\.")` for example. Personally I prefer the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.com) library [`Splitter`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter) class instead, but it's your choice :)

EDIT: From a comment:

> Also do you recommend I use an String array to store a mix of integer and character values? Say for futureproofing I might want to do a comparison on say if (age > 21) then John can drink.

No. Once you've split the data into a string array, it would be good to convert that into an object specifically for this data. For example:

```
String[] bits = text.split("\t");
// Assuming a suitable constructor...
Person person = new Person(bits[1], bits[0], Integer.parseInt(bits[2]));
System.out.println(person.getFavouriteFruit()); // Apple
```

Comment: So what happens when I have `Skeet\t\t23`? (If a field is left blank) will the array still be `{Skeet, NULL, 23}`?

Comment: @meiryo It will be `{"Skeet", "", "23"}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String str = "Apple\tJohn\t23";
    String[] parts = str.split("\t");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

> The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these expressions:

```
Regex   Result
:   { "boo", "and", "foo" }
o   { "b", "", ":and:f" }
```

Comment: Thanks Amit! Also do you recommend I use an String array to store a mix of integer and character values? Say for futureproofing I might want to do a comparison on say if (age > 21) then John can drink.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(String str)` is there for you but don't miss to catch `NumberFormatException`