# 2D array[row][] = str.split("\t") not behaving as expected

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Whilst I can get it to work on a 1 dimension array (`String array[] = str.split(blah)`), I have trouble on 2D arrays. I'm using a loop that goes through each **row** of the 2D array and assigns it whatever `str.split(\t)` has.

For example:

```
John\tSmith\t23
James\tJones\t21
```

My 2D array will look like this: `{{John, Smith, 23}, {James, Jones, 21}}`
I've only begun Java so I'm not too sure about some of the syntax for 2D arrays.

EDIT: Some code as requested

```
String str;
int row = 0;
String array[][];
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    array[row] = str.split("\t");
    System.out.println(array[row][0]);
    row++;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error are you getting? Can we see some code please?

Comment: Do you mean `array[0] = "John\tSmith\t23".split("\t");`? Are you getting a NullPointerException? If so did you allocate any space to the array?

Comment: You cave to initialize your array before using it. You just declared it so far.

Comment: @Peter and Baz What if the data I want to put in the array is dynamic?
This was my previous question on SO it might add some context:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370657/convert-a-string-last-tfirst-tage-to-an-array-with-elements-last-first-age

Comment: @meiryo Then don't use arrays. Use a `List` instead, like [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize your array as follows:

```
int rowCount = ...;
String array[][] = new String[rowCount][];
```

or in case you don't know the number of rows, you may use ArrayList instead:

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String str;
while((str = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] array = str.split("\t");
    list.add(array);
}
String[][] array2D = new String[list.size()][];
list.toArray(array2D);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `str.split("\\\\t");` The split method accepts a regular expression.
Check this [post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635764/string-parsing-in-java-with-delimeter-tab-t-using-split)

Answer (score 1):

Your `String array[][]` must be initialized before use it.

If you can, move your code to use `List`s to make it work:

```
List<List<String>> array = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    array.add(Arrays.asList(str.split("\t")));
}
```

In case you must not use `List`, then initialize your array

```
final int SIZE = ...; //some value that would be the max size of the array of arrays
String array[][] = new String[SIZE][];
```